# URL property for webview not working for Android,but works fine for IOS

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I am creating webview in Titanium appcelerator & trying to access a "remote URL" from server. I can able to get "pdf" contents for that URL in IOS devices, but in Android i'm getting the following error.

```
"Enterprise Container Manager" - Policy service is not ready.
```

I'm getting same error in Android even if i hardcode that URL inside webview.Is there is any limitation in Android to get PDF file in webview?

And i'm also getting following error in log;

```
11-13 19:43:20.145: E/webview(10765): registerForStylusPenEvent onAttachedToWindow
11-13 19:43:20.145: E/webview(10765): registerForStylusPenEvent START
11-13 19:43:20.145: E/webview(10765): registerForStylusPenEvent END
11-13 19:43:20.900: E/webview(10765): removeForStylusPenEvent onDetachedFromWindow
11-13 19:43:20.900: E/webview(10765): removeForStylusPenEvent START
11-13 19:43:20.900: E/webview(10765): removeForStylusPenEvent END
11-13 19:43:21.085: E/Sensors(2294): Acc old sensor_state 1, new sensor_state : 0 en : 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS has a file QuickView embedded in the webview for viewing PDF's and other documents, Android does not have this, you cannot render PDF's with a vanilla webview in android.

To support PDF viewing, you can use Intents, or get a module from the marketplace, or make your own module wrapping a library like [MuPDF](https://code.google.com/p/apv/).